# Is it possible to remove rosdep

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm developing a project with ROS and have a question now.

I found that `rosdep` is really huge (Installing `rosdep` will increase the dist usage of `/usr` about 700 MB). As I know, `rosdep` is to solve the dependency issue. So I'm thinking if I can remove the whole `rosdep` to save my disk space. If possible, what should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284752/is-it-possible-to-remove-rosdep/) by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can remove rosdep by calling `sudo apt-get remove python-rosdep` however if you're looking to clean up disk space that's not what you want. Rosdep's size is well under 1 MB.

What you're probably seeing is the dependencies that you asked rosdep to install for you. They will need to be uninstalled just like any other package you installed. To get a list of what rosdep installed for a workspace use the `--reinstall --simulate` options and reinvoke `rosdep install` like you did before.

Note that when you uninstall these dependencies anything that relies on them will no longer work.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2